# Python requests call not handling authentication as expected

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a list in which I am putting the url and authentication parameters for a requests get call.  If I try the call this way I get authentication error (401) but if I break out the auth by itself explicitly on the call things work.  Why can't I include auth in this manner and expect it to properly "explode" in the call?

```
parms = []
parms.append(url)
parms.append('auth=(''UID'', ''PWD'')')
response = requests.get(*parms)
```

This results in 404 because it is not recognizing the authentication.  BUT, if I do this it works.  To me these seem the same.  The single quotes are only different to get the string to append in the list properly.  I thought the first way would result in 2 parameters - url and auth

```
parms = []
parms.append(url)
response = requests.get(*parms, auth=('UID', 'PWD'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is equivalent to the following:

```
requests.get(url, "auth=('UID', 'PWD')")
```

When you really want:

```
requests.get(url, auth=('UID', 'PWD'))
```

You must use this instead:

```
args = []
kwargs = {}

args.append(url)
kwargs['auth'] = ('UID', 'PWD')

requests.get(*args, **kwargs)
```

The rule is:

- when you have `function(foo, bar)` you are using positional parameters, they go into `*args`.
- when you have `function(foo=1, bar=2)` you are using named parameters, they go into `**kwargs`.
- you can mix both, in Python 2 positional parameters must be placed before named parameters.

Comment: Thank you - that helps alot.  One other question if I may - I am pulling the authentication information from a database - the "('UID', 'PWD')" piece.  But when it comes from the database it is a string.  It appears what is passing to the dictionary is not a string, per se (no single quotes around the value ('UID', 'PWD').  If I put my database result in the dictionary I get an error "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
".  How do I convert my database string to whatever it is called for getting it properly in the dictionary?

Comment: I figured the second issue out - I do the following - kwargs['auth']=ast.literal_eval(header[2]).  This puts in the dictionary value the representation I need for the request call to work.

Comment: Nice! `ast.literal_eval` is safe (never use the plain `eval` with user-provided data)